# Bash run script from script using variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run bash script from bash script using variable.

The variable is assigned before from parsed CSV, and when I echo it the path to another script looks ok. When I try to run the script path from the variable it fails.

Assiging the variable (2nd column from csv):

```
THE_VARIABLE=`echo ${CHOICE[${WHICH}]} | awk -F";" '{print $2}'`
```

echo $THE_VARIABLE (ok):

```
/fake_path/scripts/test.sh
```

Bash debug:

```
    + echo $'/fake_path/scripts/test.sh\r'
```

However after that when trying to run:

```
bash $THE_VARIABLE
: No such file or directoryripts/test.sh
```

It seems like taking only part of the string in variable(?).

Thanks for help!

Comment: can't reproduce that

Comment: Please provide output of :- echo "#$THE_VARIABLE#"

Comment: Could be the \r for the carriage return causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, this cannot be fully reproduced without having all the code and the csv.

I know only basics of bash and I am wondering why its cuts the string assigned to variable when trying to run it (echo is ok).

Maybe some Bash parameter?

Comment: @grail
echo "#$THE_VARIABLE#" ----> 
#/fakepath/scripts/test.sh

Comment: @RamanSailopal
Any way how to remove \r? When echo I dont see it, only when debuging.

Comment: If you run echo -e $THE_VARIABLE you should be able to see it echo disables escape sequences when used with no flags

Comment: @RamanSailopal - echo -e shows correct clean path. /fake_path/scripts/test.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string ends with ASCII character 13 (\x0D or \015 or \r) and not the sequence `'\' 'r'`, with `echo` the trailing `\r` can't be seen because echo adds a `\n`, but appending a `#` character for example will show at begining of line.

```
echo "${THE_VARIABLE}#"
#fake_path/scripts/test.sh
```

to remove the trailing `\r`:

```
THE_VARIABLE=${THE_VARIABLE%$'\r'}
```

otherwise it means that input file has dos line ending `\r\n`, it could be modified with `dos2unix`.

Comment: Perfect! I just run dos2unix on the csv file and everything works. 
Thanks!